# MySQL - Extract records present in a table but not in another

Tags: c#, mysql

I know this question has already been asked many times.
The problem is that other solutions don't work..
I tried the following:

```
SELECT ID FROM TABLE_1 AS T1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT COLUMN_1,COLUMN_2 FROM TABLE_2 AS T2 WHERE T1.COLUMN_1 = T2.COLUMNS_1 AND T1.COLUMN_2 = T2.COLUMN_2);
```

It always go in timeout, both from Workbench and from code (I am using Visual Studio 2013 C#).
I don't know how to make the query easier in order to make it work.. Maybe split it in 2..

Example:

```
Table 1                                   Table 2
ID COLUMN_1 COLUMN_2                      ID COLUMN_1 COLUMN_2
1  0        1                             1  0        1
2  0        1                             2  0        1
3  0        1                             3  0        1
4  1        2                            
5  1        2                             
6  1        2
```

It should return

> 1        2

Or also only the ID (2).

Comment: Do you have indices on those tables? Specifically on the columns you query?

Comment: I don't know what you mean.. But I don't think that I have them

Comment: @ayasha "Indices" is a plural form of "index". You should know what that is. Also timeouts may indicate a problem with connection itself, are you sure that's fine? How much data do you have in your tables?

Comment: The connection is fine, I have reduced the table to 20k records, and it still doesn't work..

Comment: If you don't know what indices are, it's time to read up on them. It's really too much to fit into an SO post, I suggest you read a basic book about database design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
     Table_1.ID 
    ,Table_1.COLUMN_1 
    ,Table_1.COLUMN_2 
FROM Table_1 

LEFT JOIN Table_2
    ON Table_1.ID = Table_2.ID
    AND Table_1.COLUMN_1 = Table_2.COLUMN_1
    AND Table_1.COLUMN_2 = Table_2.COLUMN_2

WHERE Table_2.ID  IS NULL
```

**Edit:**
Well, if you don't need to match the id, then it's simply:

```
SELECT 
     Table_1.ID 
    ,Table_1.COLUMN_1 
    ,Table_1.COLUMN_2 
FROM Table_1 

LEFT JOIN Table_2
    ON Table_2.COLUMN_1 = Table_1.COLUMN_1
    AND Table_2.COLUMN_2 = Table_1.COLUMN_2

WHERE Table_2.ID  IS NULL
```

If that's still too slow, maybe an index can help. 
If an index doesn't help, you can still increase the command [timeout](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand.html#connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand-commandtimeout).

Still, another option would be:

```
SELECT 
     Table_1.ID 
    ,Table_1.COLUMN_1 
    ,Table_1.COLUMN_2 
FROM Table_1 
WHERE 
(COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2) NOT IN (SELECT COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2 FROM Table_2)
```

Comment: That's basically the same query, the database has to do the same join operation. Why would you expect it to be faster than the original?

Comment: this should work like expected. Left join work efficient than exist/not exist clauses

Comment: Yes it's fast..but the problem is that ID can be different between the two tables, it's not true that for the same ID I have the same records..so I can not use JOIN

Comment: @ayasha: Adopted it for that case.

Comment: @nvoigt: It depends on the number of rows in the table. With few, exists is faster. With many many rows, left join is faster. http://sqlserverplanet.com/tsql/comparing-exists-vs-left-join-where-not-null